# Setting ui-locales within Azure AD B2C sign in from within the application (.NET Core)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, localization, azure-ad-b2c

I am developing ASP.NET Core application which utilizes Azure AD B2C for user management. I would like to have sign in /up form being localized to multiple languages. I have added new languages for policies in Azure AD B2C management dashboard in Azure portal.

Now I would like to set `ui-locales` parameter (as described on [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization)) when calling out to Azure AD B2C from my application. This is a piece which I am not able to achieve as I am not sure where I can inject this parameter and need help.

Comment: Note that in Saca's response below, the query string parameter ui_locales has underscore and not a dash (like in your question).

Comment: @marek_lani Can you please flag this question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways to support localization:

- Let B2C serve the appropriate language based on the user's browser settings. For this, you shouldn't need to pass a ui_locales parameter, just [enable localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization#support-uilocales-requested-languages), [define the languages you want to support](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization#select-which-languages-your-user-journey-supports) and B2C will do the right thing for you.
- Alternatively, you can explicitly tell B2C which locale to serve up by sending the `ui_locales` query string parameter in your authorization request, for example: `ui_locales=en-us`

Full examples:

- French (add ui_locales=fr-fr): https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tdlrv2.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=1fc82d11-53ed-45e9-ba60-82797f1c0f82&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2ftdlrb2c.azurewebsites.net%2f&response_mode=form_post&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&ui_locales=fr-fr
- Spanish (add ui_locales=es-es): https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tdlrv2.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=1fc82d11-53ed-45e9-ba60-82797f1c0f82&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2ftdlrb2c.azurewebsites.net%2f&response_mode=form_post&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&ui_locales=es-es

In C# and ASP.Net, one option to do this is by adding the query string parameter in the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event (see [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L94) example, though the event is used for something else, you'd use the same pattern).

Answer (score 3):

The Wingtip Games sample at [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Startup.cs) sets the `ui_locales` query string parameter in the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event as follows:

```
// If an Account controller action has set a UI locale (e.g. to "fr"), then set the UI locales parameter for
// the authentication request to this UI locale.
if (context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey(Constants.AuthenticationPropertiesKeys.UILocales))
{
    context.ProtocolMessage.UiLocales = context.Properties.Items[Constants.AuthenticationPropertiesKeys.UILocales];
    context.Properties.Items.Remove(Constants.AuthenticationPropertiesKeys.UILocales);
}
```

Comment: Chris Padgett, this is not working when the user cancels the B2C flow during signup. When cancelling, the use ris redirected to the .Net core index page and the locale is lost (falls to the default). Any idea to improve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

With some help of examples of @[Chris Padgett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7378174/chris-padgett) I created this solution:

Create an AzureADB2COpenIdConnectOptionsConfigurator object:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Forestbrook.Azure.ADB2C
{
    public class AzureADB2COpenIdConnectOptionsConfigurator : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
    {
        public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = WrapOpenIdConnectEvent(options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider, OnRedirectToIdentityProvider);
        }

        public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            => Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);

        private static Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context)
        {
            // TODO: Get your language setting
            var language = GetLanguage(context.HttpContext);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
                context.ProtocolMessage.UiLocales = language;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private static Func<TContext, Task> WrapOpenIdConnectEvent<TContext>(Func<TContext, Task> baseEventHandler, Func<TContext, Task> thisEventHandler)
            => async context => { await baseEventHandler(context); await thisEventHandler(context); };

        // Example: get selected language from standard Asp.Net Core cookie:
        private static string GetLanguage(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (!httpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName, out var value))
                return null;

            // Cookie value looks like: "c=nl-NL|uic=en-US". uic defines the language.
            var split = value.Split('=', '|');
            if (split.Length < 4)
                return null;

            return split[3];
        }
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs, in the ConfigureServices method, add this line AFTER AddAzureADB2C:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
// Add this line:
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, AzureADB2COpenIdConnectOptionsConfigurator>();
```