# Language Customization in Dynamic 365 Portal Integrating with Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

**Scenario:**
Integrate Dynamic 365 Portal with Azure Active Directory(AAD) B2C by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/azure-ad-b2c) and enable Multi Language.

**Issue**:
When I try implementing a login flow for the Dynamics 365 Portals (Also known as Power Apps Portals), the AAD B2C is not getting the **ui_locales**, instead it is getting automatically the Browser context language, but what I need is to set the language as the Dynamics Portals Language at that moment.
By the Dynamics 365 Portals side, we are not able to add this query string with the ui_locales parameter to the AAD B2C url.

**Question**:
How we can provide the ui_locales parameter from Dynamics 365 Portals to the AAD B2C? Is there a way to concatenate the string with the ui_locales parameter to the AAD B2C login url or is there any other way I can achieve this?

Appreciate your help here!!

Comment: Did you get change to look into this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333513/setting-ui-locales-within-azure-ad-b2c-sign-in-from-within-the-application-net)?

Comment: @DhivyaG-MSFTIdentity The thread which you shared is for .Net Application. I am able to do this in .Net but not in Dynamic 365 Portal. The Portal support B2C language based on browser setting but not working to add ui_locales explicitly. I need some guidance on how to add the parameter when the flow initiate via Dynamic 365/PowerApp Portal.

Comment: Can you please confirm us if you are still looking for help on this

Comment: I able to execute the above scenario by implementing custom solution, but do please let me know if there is some inbuilt feature to do it.