# AD B2C - ui_locales not propagated from SignIn to PasswordReset

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have configured AD B2C localization, by using with `ui_locales` query string parameter to manage translations.

I followed the following guide, for custom policies:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

The feature is working fine for the sign-in page, and the language setting is correctly propagated to the sign-up page. Unfortunately, when I move to the password reset page, my `ui_locales` is not in the URL anymore (if I manually set it, while in page, it works).

As a possible workaround, I tried to inject the query string parameter to the URL by using javascript, but the forgot-password URL is not resolved as-is.

From an url like this (I added ui_locales with js):

```
https://myb2c.b2clogin.com/myb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/forgotPassword?csrf_token=<OMISSIS>&p=B2C_1A_signup_signin&ui_locales=it
```

I got redirected to this one:

```
https://myb2c.b2clogin.com/myb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_passwordreset/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<OMISSIS>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.it%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fmyb2c.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fpeople.read%20https%3A%2F%2Fmyb2c.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fpeople.write&response_mode=form_post&nonce=<OMISSIS>&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.1.4.1.0&ui_locales=en&state=<OMISSIS>&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0
```

As you may have noticed, an `ui_locales` appears (with value `en`) but is not coherent with the originally requested one (`it`).

Do anyone know how can I resolve this issue? Thank you!

**Update**:
Using the embedded password reset flow as indicated by Jas Suri, solved the problem, btw the new button appears among the social login ones, so it looks like I should use some js/css to keep the usual feeling:

[image]

**Update 2**:
The wrong link position was due to the missing `forgotPasswordLinkOverride` setting in the Extensions xml.

Comment: Thanks @McBodge and Could you please look this document for using ui_locales concept. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333513/setting-ui-locales-within-azure-ad-b2c-sign-in-from-within-the-application-net/ Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you @Jit_MSFT. Actually, I'm able to pass ui_locales from my app to AD B2C. It works well in the login page and it gets correctly propagated from the login page to the registration page. Unfortunately, it's not present in the Forgot Password page (that I access from the login page).

Comment: @Jit_MSFT just to clarify: I have no control on the way the forgot password link is generated in the login form, since it's AD B2C that actually build the form, in the following way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy