# ADB2C Password Reset page localization

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are using custom policies with ADB2C and are passing ui_locales in the signup_signin url for the localization. However, B2C doesn't propagate this to the Self Service Password Reset flow. We set it up following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#self-service-password-reset-recommended

Is there a way to propagate ui_locales to Password Reset form in Custom Policies? The url for Password Reset is out of our control and is constructed by B2C itself.

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can surely **configure the page localization option for the ‘Password Reset’ policy page by configuring the ‘Azure AD B2C Embedded Password Reset’ flow wherein the default ‘Password Reset’ flow policy gives out the error code ‘AADB2C90118’ when a specific password reset policy is not invoked through the custom policy**.

•   Thus, **to use the ‘Azure AD B2C Embedded Password Reset’ flow policy in your Azure AD B2C Custom policy, kindly follow the below link for more details wherein the ‘B2C_1A_Demo_SignUp_SignIn_SSPR’ custom policy is used instead of the default ‘SigninOrSignUp’ starter policy**: -

**https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset/policy**

If you use the above specified custom policy, then **ensure to include the below ‘Localization’ element in the ‘TrustedFrameworkExtensions.xml’ file such that supported languages are made available in the custom policy** accordingly: -

```
<Localization Enabled="true">
<SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
<SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
<SupportedLanguage>es</SupportedLanguage>
</SupportedLanguages>
</Localization>
```

•   Once, the above localization code is made available in the **‘TrustedFrameworkExtensions.xml’ file**, ensure that the below option in the image occurs for you to translate the **‘Reset Password’** to be able to display as shown below such that when selected, the **respective language is available for display and resetting the password**.

[image: Azure B2C Password reset localization]

To know more about this, please refer the below link for more details: -

***[AD B2C - ui_locales not propagated from SignIn to PasswordReset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66449017/ad-b2c-ui-locales-not-propagated-from-signin-to-passwordreset)***